# How can i remove the text decoration from a list item wrapped in an <a> tag, using a query selector?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to **remove the textDecoration** from a special item using a *javascript* ( preferably a query selector. I don't know what I'm doing wrong though. Here's the code. [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Champion36O/pen/KqgRdX)

```
<h1>Thanks for the Help!</h1>
  <h1> My problem set </h1>
  <ul>
    <li id="highlight">List Item 1</li>
    <li class="bolded">List Item 2</li>
    <a href="#" class="special"><li class="bolded">List Item 3</li></a>
  </ul>

var sLi = document.querySelector("ul a.special");
for (var i = 0; i <= sLi.length; i++){
  sLi[i].style.textDecoration = "none";
}
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You can't have a `<a>` as a child of a `<ul>`

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to loop over your query result since `querySelector()` only returns one item.

Had you been using `querySelectorAll()`, you would want the loop as that returns a node list.

```js
var sLi = document.querySelector("ul a.special");
sLi.style.textDecoration = "none";
```

```html
<h1>Thanks for the Help!</h1>
  <h1> My problem set </h1>
  <ul>
    <li id="highlight">List Item 1</li>
    <li class="bolded">List Item 2</li>
    <li class="bolded"><a href="#" class="special">List Item 3</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Also (FYI), the `li` should contain the `a` and not the other way around.